# No of ways of placing k distinguishable items into n distinguishable boxes

Tags: python-2.7, combinations, combinatorics

[Distinguishable objects into distinguishable boxes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/468824/distinguishable-objects-into-distinguishable-boxes?rq=1)

It is very similar to this question posted.
I'm trying to get python code for this question. 
Note although it is similar there is a key difference. i.e.
A bucket can be empty, while the other buckets contain all the items. Even this case will be considered as a separate case.

for example:

Consider I have 3 items A,B,C and 3 buckets B1, B2, B3

The table below will show the expected result:

```
B1          B2       B3
(A,B,C)     ()       ()
()        (A,B,C)    ()
()          ()      (A,B,C)
(A)         (B)      (C)
(A)         (C)      (B)
(B)         (A)      (C)
(B)         (C)      (A)
(C)         (B)      (A)
(C)         (A)      (B)
(A,B)       (C)      ()
(A,B)       ()       (C)
(B,C)       (A)      ()
(B,C)       ()       (A)
(A,C)       (B)      ()
(A,C)       ()       (B)
()          (A,B)    (C)
(C)         (A,B)    ()
()          (B,C)    (A)
(A)         (B,C)    ()
()          (A,C)    (B)
(B)         (A,C)    ()
()          (C)      (A,B)
(C)          ()      (A,B)
()          (A)      (B,C)
(A)          ()      (B,C)
()          (B)      (A,C)
(B)          ()      (A,C)

Length is 27.
```

```
>>def make_sets(items, num_of_baskets=3):
      pass
>>make_sets(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), 3)
```

I'm expecting the output of a function to give me these combinations in a form of list of lists of tuples. I'm saying this again the number of items is variable and the number of buckets is variable too.

** Please provide python code for the make_sets function.

If someone can explain the math combinatorics. I'd greatly appreciate that too. I spent more than 2 days on this problem without reaching a definite solution.

Answer (score 0):

Think about bringing in the items one by one, and each of them having to select a box to land on.

Start with the first item, it has `n` possible choices. Now the second item comes in, it also has `n` possible box choices.  Since items and boxes are all distinguishable, we do not need to worry about discounting permutations (as one usually needs to do for indistinguishable items).  The total number of different possibilities up to this point is `n x n`.

Bring in the third item, it also has `n` choices, and so the total number of possibilities is now `n x n x n`.

You may have noticed by now that the answer is `n^k` when you have `k` items.

In the example mentioned,  `n=3` and `k=3`, so we have `3^3 = 27` possible ways of placing the items.

The code to get a list with all of the actual combinations is shown below:

```
import itertools

def make_sets(items, num_of_boxes=3):
    allpossible = []

    for tup in itertools.product(range(num_of_boxes), repeat=len(items)):
        boxes = [list() for _ in range(num_of_boxes)]
        for item, box in zip(items, tup):
            boxes[box].append(item)

        allpossible.append(boxes)

    return allpossible

for p in make_sets(('A', 'B', 'C')):
    for box in p:
        print str(box).ljust(20),
    print
```

Running the above prints out:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']      []                   []                  
['A', 'B']           ['C']                []                  
['A', 'B']           []                   ['C']               
['A', 'C']           ['B']                []                  
['A']                ['B', 'C']           []                  
['A']                ['B']                ['C']               
['A', 'C']           []                   ['B']               
['A']                ['C']                ['B']               
['A']                []                   ['B', 'C']          
['B', 'C']           ['A']                []                  
['B']                ['A', 'C']           []                  
['B']                ['A']                ['C']               
['C']                ['A', 'B']           []                  
[]                   ['A', 'B', 'C']      []                  
[]                   ['A', 'B']           ['C']               
['C']                ['A']                ['B']               
[]                   ['A', 'C']           ['B']               
[]                   ['A']                ['B', 'C']          
['B', 'C']           []                   ['A']               
['B']                ['C']                ['A']               
['B']                []                   ['A', 'C']          
['C']                ['B']                ['A']               
[]                   ['B', 'C']           ['A']               
[]                   ['B']                ['A', 'C']          
['C']                []                   ['A', 'B']          
[]                   ['C']                ['A', 'B']          
[]                   []                   ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Hi Pedro. +1 for the answer. Do you think you can whip up python code easily for this problem?

Comment: the short answer to that would be `lambda items, num_of_baskets: num_of_baskets**items`.  However, don't know if you are thinking about some sort of simulation of the process itself.

Comment: I kind of want the make_sets function to be called and return a list of list of tuples.

Comment: ok, updated answer with the code.  used lists for the deeper level rather than tuples, so I could append

Answer (score 0):

Notice that this corresponds to base-n numbers (I hope you can beautify the output). This solution is independent of n and k:

```
n = 3
k = 4
a = [0] * k
def to_base_n(x):
    num = 0
    while x is not 0:
        num *= 10
        num += x % n
        x //= n
    return num
for i in range(0, n ** k):
    s = ('%0' + str(k) + 'd') % (to_base_n(i))
    x = [list() for _ in range(n)]
    for i in range(k):
        x[int(s[i])].append(str(i))
    print(x)
```