# Efficient Matlab Enumeration of all possible distributions of n distinguishable balls into k distinguishable boxes

Tags: matlab, combinations, permutation, enumeration, discrete-mathematics

There are 5 balls named `B1,B2,B3,B4,B5` for simplicity. Then there are 3 boxes, say `b1,b2,b3`.

There are `3^5` ways for example:-

```
B1,B2|B4|B3,B5

B1,B4|B5|B3,B2

...
```

My implementation is as follows:-

```
function distributions=compute_balls_in_boxes(balls,boxes)

c = dec2base(0:boxes^balls-1,boxes,balls)-'0';
distributions=cell(boxes^balls,1);
for i=1:size(c,1)
    curr=cell(boxes,1);
    for j=1:balls
        curr{c(i,j)+1}=[curr{c(i,j)+1};j];
    end
    distributions{i}=curr;
end

end
```

A python solution is [available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38219231/4023805). I am looking for more efficient matlab way of doing this. Can someone suggest faster matlab implementation? For example i use cell of cells in my solution which i think is very inefficient. Even `dec2base` is a bulky function.

Comment: Can we see an output excerpt for which your code fails?

Comment: I have given my code solution.